# C# use same mysql databse with my website

Tags: c#, database, mysql

The title pretty much says it all.
I have a website hosted with ubuntu with mysql on it. Now I'm trying to figure out how can I use that same mysql with c# app.

I have understood that mysql blocks connections from other IP. The problem is that with c# app the connection can come from any IP Address.

In another question I left on stackoverflow someone said that it's not good to accept all connections.

What should I do to connect my website data with my c# app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your C# app is a desktop client because you say "the connection can come from any IP Address". The answer largely depends on whether you're distributing this to users or you just plan to use yourself or give it to a few people that you trust entirely.

If it's going to be distributed to end users, you *must not* give the application credentials to connect directly to your database. Even read-only credentials can wreak havok on your database if uncontrolled. Instead you should implement a web service that accepts requests from the C# application and performs queries and mutations on the database as necessary on behalf of the client. This will eliminate your problem of any IP address accessing your database, and you'll only have to whitelist the servers that are running your new service.

If used by yourself or people you trust, you can either open your database to whitelist specific IP addresses, or allow your users to connect to your database through a [tunnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunneling_protocol). This would significantly decrease the amount of work you have to do, but it's not very secure. Your users can gain access to your database credentials and use them maliciously if they decided to. Creating a service is still the best design, but I would consider this a viable option only for something like a support tool used internally within an organization.

Comment: Ok thank you. Like making API  with php and sending c# post and get requests

Comment: @Toni yes that's right